# Kentico Compilation Error CS1061 synching new field

Tags: asp.net, synchronization, crm, microsoft-dynamics, kentico

Not a ASP dev, trying to help the non-profit I work for IT dept sync a new field from Dynamics CRM to kentico 5.5R2.

I added the field to crm, and added it to the view that seems to be what checks which fields to push to the CMS (based on similar types of fields) and published the changes.

I added the field to Kentico in the "Document Types" section under "fields". While looking for the place where the system sets the CMS field to the value of the CRM field I thought I found it in a file CRMsynchronize.cs. All the working fields seemed to be declared there (whoever developed this site seemed to hard code a lot of things) when I add the new field here I get an error:

> CS1061: 'Crm.new_workshopmanagement' does not contain a definition for
>   'new_tierpriceinfo' and no extension method 'new_tierpriceinfo'
>   accepting a first argument of type 'Crm.new_workshopmanagement' could
>   be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Not sure if there is an additional step I'm missing, not a backend dev but being a front end person with some PHP experience it seems like a lot of the code on this site was not done in a thought out way. Any insight or help on synching new fields from a CRM to a CMS would be appreciated.

Comment: I think I solved it. It looks like you also need to add the field to a crmservice file. If there is something wrong with this method or a better way I would appreciate it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the error it seems that you've forgotten to regenerate the CRM proxy class.
You can use `CrmSvcUtil.exe` from the MS Dynamics CRM SDK to do that.

```
CrmSvcUtil.exe /url:http://<serverName>/<organizationName>/XRMServices/2011/Organization.svc    /out:<outputFilename>.cs /username:<username> /password:<password> /domain:<domainName>    /namespace:<outputNamespace> /serviceContextName:<serviceContextName>
```

Check out the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg327844.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) and make sure you download an SDK corresponding with your version of MS Dynamics.